# laminating hardwood to plywood

Tags: woodworking

can I laminate hardwood boards to plywood to make a thicker looking board.  I am making a table top and the only boards I have available are 5/8".  I would like to make it 1 1/4" if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can laminate hard wood to plywood. I have done this many times using a quality wood glue and clamps. In some cases with thinner hard wood I will use a 2nd sheet of plywood to help apply pressure to the veneer after it drys sand and finish like any other wood surface.

Comment: Now you just have to decide on how to finish the edge. Will the top extend Over the edge trim or wii the edge trim finish flush with the top?